# Bounding Box in Matlab (regionprops)

Tags: matlab, bounding-box, image-segmentation

I am writing a Matlab program to segment an image and then put a bounding box around the segmented image. My code was previously working, however I am now getting the error:

> - Error using rectangle
> - Value must be a 4 element vector

The array in question is BoundingBox created by regionprops, which *should* contain only four elements, however is for some reason containing more. Here is my code (the defaultSegment function returns a binary image):

```
function [ boundImage ] = boundSegment( input_image )
image = defaultSegment(input_image);
clear s;
s = regionprops(image, 'Area', 'BoundingBox');
numObj = numel(s);
index = 1;
for k = 1: numObj-1
    if s(k+1).Area > s(index).Area
        index = k+1;
    else
        index = index;
    end
end
figure, imshow(input_image);
rectangle('Position',s(index).BoundingBox);
boundImage = null;
```

(I would actually prefer if my code could could directly put the bounding box on the image instead of subplotting it, but I haven't found a way to do that without the vision toolbox)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the value of `s(index).BoundingBox` to ensure its a `4 element vector`?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. s(index).BoundingBox is NOT giving a 4 element vector, but I cannot figure out why this is the case.

Comment: see this link on how to get the size of the segment and set the bounding box http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157  you will have to download a matlab file

Comment: That link was not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `image` has more than two dimensions. Check that using `size(image)`. `BoundingBox` will have four elements only if `image` has two dimensions. From [Matlab's regionprops help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf):

> 'BoundingBox' — The smallest rectangle containing the region, a 1-by-Q *2 vector, where Q is the number of image dimensions: ndims(L), ndims(BW), or numel(CC.ImageSize).

The reason an image would have a third dimension is for multiple color channels. If you want to convert to grayscale for processing, use [rgb2gray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That must be my problem.  When I do `size(image)` I get  1080        1520           3. Why would the image be three dimensional, and how do I convert it to a two dimensional image?

Comment: Because there are three color channels.  To get a 2d matrix use `mean( image,3 )`

Comment: Thank you for your help. You answer helped me identify my problem, which was actually that I had two functions of the same name (defaultSegment) saved in two different locations, and the location I was calling boundSegment from was with the defaultSegment that produced a color image instead of a binary one.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @shoelzer's answer regarding `image` with three channels,
I suspect you get color image because of your segmentation algorithm (`defaultSegment`) that paints each segment in a different color. try [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) to convert `image` to a segmentation label 2D matrix